how to find explicit formula for $f_{n+1}=af_n+\frac{b}{f_n}$?
I tried to find an explicit formula for the recurrence relation
$$f_{n+1}=af_n+\frac{b}{f_n} , f_0 \ne0$$
I will show what I got in five cases
Case1
for $f_0=-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{1-a}}\ne0$ I got that $f_n=f_0$ where $a\ne1$
Case2
if $b=0$ then it's easy to show that $f_n=a^n f_0$
Case3
if $a=\frac{1}{2}$ then by putting $u_n=\frac{f_n-\sqrt{2b}}{f_n+\sqrt{2b}}$ then
$$ u_{n+1}=(u_n)^2\to u_n=(u_0)^{2^n}$$
So
$$ f_n=-\sqrt{2b} \frac{x^{2^n}+1}{x^{2^n}-1} , x=\frac{f_0-\sqrt{2b}}{f_0+\sqrt{2b}}$$
Case4
for $a=1 , b\ne0$ I didn't get any information for $f_{n+1}=f_n+\frac{b}{f_n}$
Case5
for $a\notin\{1,\frac{1}{2}\} , b\ne0,f_0\ne-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{1-a}}$ then by putting
$$ u_n=\frac{f_n-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{1-a}}}{f_n+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{1-a}}}$$
then
$$ u_{n+1}=(u_n)^2+(2a-1)u_n$$
now my QUESTION how to find the solution in case 4 and 5 ?
is there another special values for $a,b,f_0$ to find the solution ?
I looked here and here and didn't get any ideas.

$$
{f_{n + 1} \over \sqrt{b/a}} = a\left({f_{n} \over \sqrt{b/a}} + {\sqrt{b/a} \over f_{n}}\right)
$$

For case #5, I don't see how you get the recurrence $u_n$ from the definition i.t.o. $f_n$. That notwithstanding, I can get a solution to that recurrence for a particular value of $a$. But that recurrence is definitely not the same as the starting recurrence in $f$.

@CyeWaldman just put $u_n=\frac{f_n-L}{f_n+L} , L=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{1-a}}$ which mean $f_n=-L \frac{u_n+1}{u_n-1}$ then from $f_{n+1}=af_n+\frac{b}{f_n}$ its easy to get that $u_{n+1}=(u_n)^2+(2a-1)u_n$

I have solutions for the special cases of $a=1/2$ and $b=\pm 1$. Thus, first consider
$$
f_{n+1}=\frac{ f_n }{2 }+\frac{1}{f_n}
$$
Let $g_n=\frac{ f_n }{\sqrt{2} }$, so that
$$
g_{n+1}=\frac{ g_n ^2+1}{2 g_n}
$$
Now, let $h_n=\coth^{-1}(g_n)$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
&\coth(h_{n+1})=\frac{ 1+\coth^2(h_n)}{2\coth(h_n)}=\coth(2h_n)\\
&h_{n+1}=2h_n \mapsto h_n=2^nh_0\\
&g_n=\coth(h_n)=\coth(2^nh_0)\\
&f_n=\sqrt{2}\coth(2^nh_0)
\end{align}
$$
There remain now only to express $h_0$ in terms of $f_0$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
h_0&=\coth^{-1}(g_0)\\
&= \coth^{-1}\bigg(\frac{f_0}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg(\frac{f_0+\sqrt{2}}{f_0-\sqrt{2}}\bigg)
\end{align}
$$
And, finally
$$
f_n=\sqrt{2}\coth\bigg(2^{n-1}\ln\bigg(\frac{f_0+\sqrt{2}}{f_0-\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\bigg)
$$
The solution for $b=-1$ proceeds similarly, but uses the trigonometric identity
$$
\cot(h_{n+1})=\frac{ 1-\cot^2(h_n)}{2\cot(h_n)}=\cot(2h_n)
$$
And then
$$
f_n=\sqrt{2}\cot\bigg(2^{n-1}\ln\bigg(\frac{f_0+\sqrt{2}}{f_0-\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\bigg)
$$

It still works for $a = 1/2$ and $\large “any”$ $b$: See my comment above.

but I put in the case3 solution for $a=1/2 , b\ne 0$

@Faoler As for you case #3, I am unable to verify that numerically. That could be on me, so I'll ask if you have done so.

@FelixMarin Yes, very nice, indeed.

yes its same where
$$\sqrt{2} \coth \left(-2^{n-1} \ln x \right)=-\sqrt{2} \frac{x^{2^n}+1}{x^{2^n}-1} , x=\frac{f_0-\sqrt{2}}{f_0+\sqrt{2}} , n\in N $$
also its true for $b=-1$

@Faoler I think I have found your error. I believe that you should have $$\sqrt{2b} \coth \left(2^{n-1} \ln x \right)=\sqrt{2b} \frac{x^{2^n}+1}{x^{2^n}-1} , x=\frac{f_0+\sqrt{2}}{f_0-\sqrt{2}} , n\in N$$ That is, there is no minus sign, and $x$ is inverted (i.e., the plus sign is in the numerator). I have confirmed this numerically for arbitrary rela and complex $b$ and $f_0$.

let $f_0=1 , b=1$ then
$$ \sqrt{2} \coth(-2^{n-1} \ln x)=-\sqrt{2} \frac{x^{2^n}+1}{x^{2^n}-1} , x=\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}$$
see that on wolfram
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%282%29+coth%E2%81%A1%28-2%5E%28n-1%29++ln%E2%81%A1%E3%80%96%281-%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%E3%80%97+%29-%28-sqrt%282%29%29%28%28%281-%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%29%5E%282%5En+%29%2B1%29%2F%28%28%281-%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%29%5E%282%5En+%29-1%29+where+n%3D5

I'm not questioning that, but rather, how you got that point. Now, I'll ask you again, have you verified your results numerically?

I showed in Case3 how I got the solution and yes its true numerically see in the link below I put $f_0=1,b=1$ with $n=2$ and I got $f_2=\frac{17}{12}$ which is correct
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-sqrt%282%29%29%28%28%281-%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%29%5E%282%5En+%29%2B1%29%2F%28%28%281-%E2%88%9A2%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%29%5E%282%5En+%29-1%29+where+n%3D2

This is perhaps a comment but is too lengthy present there. Here we’re addressing Case #4 in the OP, where the author purports to transform the original recurrence relation into  a simple quadratic form, i.e., one without fractions. The author proposes the transform
$$
u_n=\frac{f_n-c}{ f_n+c } \quad \text{  or } \quad f_n=-c\frac{u_n+1}{ u_n-1}
$$
where $c=\sqrt{b/(1-a)}$, leading to the equation
$$
u_{n+1}= u_n^2+(2a-1)u_n
$$
We were unable to verify this numerically and undertook to carry out the transform ourself. We found that
$$
u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2+(2a-1)u_n}{(2a-1)u_n+1}
$$
This solution has been verified numerically. It is not the desired quadratic equation. However, it is not totally without merit. Notice that when $a=1/2$ the equation reduces to the simple, and solvable,
$$
u_{n+1}=u_n^2
$$
Now, we have already seen two solutions for the case of $a=1/2$, in the OP and in my previous Answer. They are different solutions, but equivalent. Here we will find yet another form of the solution. Thus, let $v_n=\ln u_n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\ln u_{n+1}=2\ln u_n\\
&v_{n+1}=2v_n\\
&v_n=2^nv_0\\
&\\
&\text{transforming in reverse…}\\
&\\
&u_n=e^{v_n}=e^{2^n v_0}\\
&f_n=-c\frac{u_n+1}{ u_n-1 }
\end{align}
$$
where $v_0=\ln u_0=\ln\bigg(\frac{f_0-c}{ f_0+c }\bigg)$.
The quadratic equation shown in the OP has some interesting properties that are worth discussing. Problems like this
$$
u_{n+1}= u_n^2+(2a-1)u_n
$$
are only solvable if they can be transformed to the form
$$
v_{n+1}=v_n^2-2
$$
The general method is to take $v_n=u_n+X$ and see if you can eliminate the $u_n$-term on the right-hand-side. In the present case, we also choose $a$ to complete the task. Suffice to say, $v_n=u_n+1$ and $a=-1/2$ to get the above equation for $v_{n+1}$. There are several ways to solve this recurrence. Perhaps the simplest is with the trigonometric identity
$$
\cos^2\alpha=\frac{1+\cos 2\alpha}{2}
$$
After a few steps it can be shown
$$
v_n=2\cos\bigg(2^n\cos^{-1}\frac{v_0}{2}\bigg)
$$
Another method is outlined here:
$$
\begin{align}
& v_{n+1}=v_n^2-2\\
&v_n=w_n+\frac{1}{w_n}\\
&w_{n+1}w_n^2=1\\
&\ln (w_{n+1}w_n^2)=0\\
&x_n=\ln w_n\\
&x_{n+1}=-2x_n\\
&x_n=2^{-n}w_0\\
\end{align}
$$
And so on. The remainder is left as an exercise for the reader.
